# Using CASE WHEN with *= operator in old SQL language

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to read this ancient SQL code and am having trouble interpreting the old style join query. Here is what the code looks like (the SELECT section omitted because I only have problem with the WHERE part:

```
  select 
  from        SAMPLE0 A,
              TABLE#DATA#SAMPLE1 B
              TABLE#DATA#SAMPLE2 C
              TABLE#DATA#SAMPLE3 D
              TABLE#DATA#SAMPLE4 E
  where       A.var1 = B.var1
  and         case when A.var2 = 'X' then A.var3 else A.var4 END *= B.var2
  and         convert(numeric(10,0),A.var5) *= convert(numeric(10,0),C.var2)
  and         D.var1 *= E.var1
  and         A.var8 >= 2000
```

What does this mean in recent SQL language? Especially the CASE WHEN part.

Comment: This may help you: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the old join syntax. Even when I first learned SQL way back in 2001, I was told not to use it. `*=` is the equivalent of `LEFT JOIN` in the new syntax.

Your query should be reworked into something like this:

```
select      *
from        SAMPLE0 A
left join   TABLE#DATA#SAMPLE1 B on A.var = B.var1
                                 and case when A.var2 = 'X' then A.var3 else A.var4 END = B.var2
left join   TABLE#DATA#SAMPLE2 C on convert(numeric(10,0),A.var5) = convert(numeric(10,0),C.var2)
cross join  TABLE#DATA#SAMPLE3 D
left join   TABLE#DATA#SAMPLE4 E on D.var1 = E.var1
where       A.var8 >= 2000
```

`FROM A, B` means a `CROSS JOIN` between `A` and `B`. When you add a `WHERE` clause it becomes an `INNER`, `LEFT`, or `RIGHT JOIN`:

```
FROM A, B                        -- CROSS JOIN
FROM A, B WHERE A.col1 = B.col1  -- INNER JOIN
FROM A, B WHERE A.col1 *= B.col1 -- LEFT JOIN
FROM A, B WHERE A.col1 =* B.col1 -- RIGHT JOIN
```

Comment: Hi Zoff Dino

Thank you very much. That is very helpful. One question though. Where in the old syntax is the cross join in the new syntax?

Thank you so much again!

Comment: I see. Thank you so much!